# C# While loop with different runtimes

Tags: c#, while-loop, dllimport

I use a C++ dll in my C# project to control a linear axis for a science project. I have to draw the position of the axis and the motorcurrent in short periods. The axis connects to my PC over LAN. 
This is the DllImport for the function to send a command to the axis.

```cs
        [DllImport("Axis3.dll", EntryPoint = "sendCommand", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
        protected static extern int m_pSendCommand(StringBuilder pcStr, StringBuilder pcRet, bool bReadLine, int iTimeOut, int iConnectionNumber);
```

During a move of the axis I use a while loop to read the position and the motorcurrent and write them to a list for a graph.

```cs
private void CollectCurrentAndPositionContinous()
        {
            bool boolAxisIsMoving;
            if (AxisIsMoving(out boolAxisIsMoving, numberofController) == 0)
            {
                while (boolAxisIsMoving == true)
                {
                    if (AxisIsMoving(out boolAxisIsMoving, numberofController) != 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    CollectCurrentAndPosition();
                }
            }
        }

        private void CollectCurrentAndPosition()
        {
            string returnText;
            int errorNumber = GetPositionandCurrent(out returnText);
            if (errorNumber == 0)
            {
                if (zedDiagram.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0) //make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve
                    return;

                LineItem curveCurrent = zedDiagram.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem; //Get the first CurveItem in the graph
                if (curveCurrent == null)
                { return; }


                IPointListEdit list = curveCurrent.Points as IPointListEdit; // Get the PointPairList

                if (list == null)// If this is null, it means the reference at curve.Points does not support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it
                { return; }

                string[] returnTextSplit = returnText.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }); //splits the returntext at space char
                double position = ConvertStringToDouble(returnTextSplit[0]);
                double currentA = ConvertStringToDouble(returnTextSplit[1]);
                double currentB = ConvertStringToDouble(returnTextSplit[2]);
                list.Add(position, currentA);
            }
            else
            {DisplayText(ErrorText(errorNumber));}
        }

        private int GetPositionandCurrent(out string o_returnText)
        {
            double position = 0.0;
            Venus3Wrapper.GetPosition(1, ref position, numberofController);
            int errorNumber = SendCommand("1 gc" + System.Environment.NewLine, out o_returnText, true, 50, numberofController);
            o_returnText = position.ToString(en.NumberFormat) + " " + o_returnText;
            return errorNumber;
        }
```

My problem is, that there are big time differences between the saved data. Two points are saved in 5ms and then there is a 100ms gap, between the next two points. I even start this function in it's own thread and redraw my diagram only every second, but the gap remains. Can somebody please give me a hint how I can get a more regular solution?

Comment: If you only log, you can send timestamps along with your axis data and not use the time of your host pc.

Comment: I edited my program to use the errornumber.
And thanks to the tip with the TCP/IP buffer I found the error. There was a problem with ACK messages from my PC. They weren't send for every second message from my controller.
As I tested my compiled program on a second PC it worked perfectly. So I tested it again on my own PC and it worked, too. It turned out although I used the release option in Visual Studio the program it was loading was the debug version. There is apparently a problem with TCP/IP. But as the release version works it doesn't bother me. Thanks for the fast help.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to re-think the protocol between your device and your PC. While I could not find the aspect of time anywhere in the code in the OP, it appears to me, that a protocol looking as described below could resolve the problems.

PC->Device: start tracing motor/axis (whatever) data.
Device->PC: Packets with accumulated measurements, each looking something like...
{ TimeStamp, Values[] }.

There are 2 use cases here. 1. Save the data for later analysis. 2. Plot the data. If you have high frequency data, no one will notice the difference if you send one value per packet (ineffective) or if you collect a bunch of data points and send them in a reasonably sized packet.

The x-axis of your graphics would not have communication and garbage collection and general PC-not-realtime-ness jitter and you can later on do more with the data in your analysis steps as the time stamp sent from the device is more reliable than the timestamps produced on PC side.

The "gaps" in your data could, on a side note also stem from nagle-algorithm if you use TCP/IP for your communications and you write single values on device side. If I remember right, nagle has 100ms timeout... collecting data for the next packet for a while before it sends. This could also explain what you see.

Comment: The dll is from the manufacturer of the axis. I don't know how it works internally. But the hint with the TCP/IP timeout could be something

Comment: Actually, yes, the statement "The axis connects to my PC over LAN" is a very good hint that the problem might be precisely this: TCP/IP on the device side waiting to collect more bytes before sending a packet.

Answer (score 0):

`m_pSendCommand()` appears to return an error code, you obtain this error code and go through the trouble of actually returning it from `GetPositionandCurrent()`, and then you proceed to completely disregard it, by only performing the body of your main `if` statement if the error code is 0 and ignoring it otherwise.

That's a recipe of disaster.  If something in the communication between your code and the device fails, `m_pSendCommand()` may be trying to tell you so, but you are not paying attention to it.  This could explain the gaps.

Comment: You're right. I will build in a working check for an error and see if there is a problem.